# Do I have to return header data from database in every controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel coming from PHP core  I'm trying to load data from the database in my header.blade.php which is included in app.blade.php.

Do I have to return the header data variable in every view? Do I have to write the same code in every controller function which is returning a view?

If there is another way to achieve that please let me know.

Currently, I have loaded data to my dashboard but it is only available to the dashboard. Please help me out.

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {   
        
          $users = User::with('companies')
          ->where('id' , auth()->user()->id)
          ->get();

        return view('dashboard')
        ->with('users',$users);
    }
}
```

here is header.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm clear-fix">
<div class="container-fluid">
    @guest
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
            {{ config('app.name', '') }}
        </a>
    @endguest

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
        @auth
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <div class="dropdown open">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="triggerId"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                           Companies
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="triggerId">
                            @foreach ($users as $user)
                                @foreach ($user->copmanies as $company)
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $company->name }}</a>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Business
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Short-term cash-flow</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business snapshot</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('invoices.view', '1') }}">Invoices</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('quotes.view', '1') }}">Quotes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('sales_overview', '1') }}">Sales Overview</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('bills.view', '1') }}">Bills</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('purchaseorders.view', '1') }}">Purchase Orders</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('purchases_overview', '1') }}">Purchase Overview</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Expense claim</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Products and srevices</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pay run</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cheques</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Accouting
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bank Account</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reports</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Advance</a>
                        <hr>
                        <p><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Reports</p>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accounts Transactions</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Aged Payable Summary</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Aged Reciveable Summary</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance Sheet</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profit And Loss</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sales Tax Report</a>
                        <hr>
                        <p><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Advance</p>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chart of accounts</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Find and record</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fixed assets</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manual journals</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Projects
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Projects</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Time entries</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Staff Time Overview</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Staff Cost Rate</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Contacts
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">All Contacts</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Customers</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Suppliers</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Employees</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Traning Customers</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        @endauth


        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <!-- Authentication Links -->
            @guest
                @if (Route::has('login'))
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endif

                @if (Route::has('register'))
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endif
            @else
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('invoices.new', '1') }}">Invoice</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('invoices.new_repeating', '1') }}">Repeating
                            Invoice</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('quotes.new', '1') }}">Qoute</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('creditnotes.new', '1') }}">Credit Note</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('bills.new', '1') }}">Bill</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('purchaseorders.new', '1') }}">Purchase Order</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Expense</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manual Journal</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spend Money</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Recive Money</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Transfer Money</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                            {{ __('Logout') }}
                        </a>

                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                            @csrf
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            @endguest
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might want to check out the concept of `trait`s (like a StandardHeaderTrait) :) Or interfaces (like a `NormalPageInterface)`

Comment: Please can you add your header blade file.

Comment: sure I have updated the details @Rwd

Comment: @Martij I have found something about sharing data to all view by using ServicesProviders  View::composer() method

Comment: Just an FYI, you can call `->first()` instead of `->get()` so that you don't have to loop through the users to just get one. Secondly, instead of having a second query to load the user, you could simply use `auth()->user()` and then to get the companies: `auth()->user()->companies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often just inline this stuff for small projects.

Your query is a bit off as well. You are getting all `User`s but only with a certain ID. This can be rewritten as:

```
User::find($id)
```

or in your case

```
User::with('companies')->find($id)
```

Also, you can just use the `\Auth::user()`. I'm an old dog but I imagine `auth()->user()` works exactly the same.

So I would inline all of that in your header:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="triggerId">
    @foreach (\Auth::user()->companies as $company)
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $company->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

If you need to really use this a lot or it gets more complex, you can Google View composers

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers

If you also always need the companies whenever you load a user, you can eager load by default using the protected `$with` variable:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Comment: Yes, the `Auth` facade and the `auth()` helpful function should both do the same thing. The only difference is that you can pass the `$guard` to the helper function instead of having to explicitly call the `guard()` method (but you still can if you want to).

Comment: @Dave Thanks for helping me didn't know that we can use models directly in our blade file.` <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="triggerId">
                                @foreach (auth()->user()->companies as $company)
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $company->name }}</a>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>`

Answer (score 2):

Personally I opt to use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers):

```
View::composer('header', function ($view) {
     $users = User::with('companies')
          ->where('id' , auth()->user()->id)->get();
    $view->with('users',$users);
    
});
```

This will ensure this view always gets the data it needs when it's composed.